# Echo out a foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, echo

I have this `array`

```
 [result] => Array
        (
    [professions] => Array
                (
                    [primary] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 755
                                    [recipes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 25255
                                            [1] => 25278
                                            [2] => 25280
```

I need to echo out all the numbers from the [recipes] array, the `25255, 25278...`

This is my start:

```
<ul class="list">';

        foreach ($r['result']['professions']['primary']['0']['recipes'] as $item) echo '

<li>
', $item['???'], '.

</li>';


echo '
                </ul>
</ul>';
```

Comment: Replace `$item['???']` with `$item`.

Comment: Oh so easy, i thought too complicated. Thanky ou!

Comment: To clarify, the `recipes` index of your result is defined as an array of numbers. You are looping through that array. So, each iteration of the loop sets `$item` to the next number in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You are going correctly.Bit modification because syntax are incorrect:-***

```
<ul class="list"> <!-- remove extra '; -->

 <?php foreach ($r['result']['professions']['primary']['0']['recipes'] as $item){
     echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>'; // instead of $item['?'] just use $item and check the concatenation
 ?>
</ul> <!-- only this much is sufficient -->
```

Comment: I would be helpful to explain your modification.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct, there are just some syntax issues. It should look more like this:

```
<ul class="list">

    <?php foreach ($r['result']['professions']['primary'][0]['recipes'] as $item) : ?>
        <li>
            <?= $item ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the syntax issues.

Comment: @Anant care to point out the syntax errors? I don't see them. (or are you calling that leftover `';` in the html a syntax error? removing... ;-) ) Feel free to edit btw.

Comment: some time editing cause bad words to me. so i did it very less